# Как мне создать декаль в билдин проекте?

Tags: unity3d

Вообщем. Мне нужно отобразить декаль на неровную поверхность. Это все в Built-in проекте (важная заметка). Есть какие либо шейдеры либо еще что то для отображения декалей? Перерыл весь инет, везде URP да hdrp

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/visual-effects-decals.html здесь сказано используйте компонент «Проектор».

Comment: gord1402, Проектор проецирует материал на ВСЕ объекты и становится их основным материалом в FOV, но мне то нужен по сути куб, текстура которого "прилипнет" к остальным, и будет изменятся в зависимости от рельефа. По сути как в первой гифке по ссылке

Comment: Нашел скрипт. Багано, лагано, но потом исправлю

Comment: Не ВСЕ объекты, там есть [Rendering Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@16.0/manual/features/rendering-layers.html)! Это указано в статье по ссылке gold1402! Было бы странно даже подумать, что никакого фильтра не существует.

Comment: Да, я знаю. Но я то ищу декали, а не покраску объектов, даже если выбрать только 1 слой, он все равно закрасит объект полностью